# Why does factoring literal value out of animated plot expression require suppression of warning?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, warning-messages, animation

I have created this simple trig animation, but it exhibits strange behavior around `ParametricPlot::plln` that I don't really understand.

If I factor out the limit of my `PlotRange` into the variable `r`, the animation throws a warning unless I suppress it with `Off[ParametricPlot::plln]`.  But in version 2, with the `PlotRange` limit included as a literal value, I don't have to disable the warning.

I'm running this in Mathematica 11.

version 1, only works with warning disabled:

```
Manipulate[Animate[Block[{
    stage = {
      LightGray, Dotted,
      InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {0, 1}], InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {1, 0}],
      Circle[], Black, Dashing[{1, 0}]
      },
    o = {0, 0},
    p = {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, px = {1, Sin[a]}, py = {Cos[a], 1},
    r = (5 Pi)/2,
    sin = ParametricPlot[{x, Sin[x + a - 1]}, {x, x1, r}],
    cos = ParametricPlot[{Cos[x + a - 1], x}, {x, y1, r}]
    },
   Off[ParametricPlot::plln];
   Show[{Graphics[{
       stage, Point[p], Point[px], Point[py],
       Line[{o, p}], Dotted, Line[{p, px}], Line[{p, py}]
       }], sin, cos
     }, PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}}]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}],
 {{x1, 1, "full sin"}, {1, -r}, Checkbox},
 {{y1, 1, "full cos"}, {1, -r}, Checkbox},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

version 2, works fine, without the warning disabled:

```
On[ParametricPlot::plln];
Manipulate[Animate[Block[{
    stage = {
      LightGray, Dotted,
      InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {0, 1}], InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {1, 0}],
      Circle[], Black, Dashing[{1, 0}]
      },
    o = {0, 0},
    p = {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, px = {1, Sin[a]}, py = {Cos[a], 1},

    sin = ParametricPlot[{x, Sin[x + a - 1]}, {x, x1, (5 Pi)/2}],
    cos = ParametricPlot[{Cos[x + a - 1], x}, {x, y1, (5 Pi)/2}]
    },

   Show[{Graphics[{
       stage, Point[p], Point[px], Point[py],
       Line[{o, p}], Dotted, Line[{p, px}], Line[{p, py}]
       }], sin, cos
     }, PlotRange -> {{-((5 Pi)/2), (5 Pi)/2}, {-((5 Pi)/2), (5 Pi)/
       2}}]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}],
 {{x1, 1, "full sin"}, {1, -((5 Pi)/2)}, Checkbox},
 {{y1, 1, "full cos"}, {1, -((5 Pi)/2)}, Checkbox},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?  Should I be concerned about needing to disable the warning?

[image: unit circle animation]

Comment: You can't use other scoped variables in declarations inside the same argument. `Block[{x = 5, y = Echo@x}, {x, y}]` that is where error originates from, if you move `sin/cos` definition to the body of `Block` it will work. p.s. use `Module` instead of `Block` if you don't need specific features it offers as it may be problematic.

Comment: arg.  well that's a dumb mistake...  :/  thanks.  The "Blocks Compared with Modules" tutorial page is actually pretty enlightening.